# How to ignore ./a.out files in git?

Tags: git

I tried this config

```
*
!.gitignore
!*.c
!*/
```

My folder structure looks like :-

```
cprograms
-program1
 -program1.c
 -a.out
-program2
 -program2.c
 -a.out
```

How to get ignore the ./a.out file.

Comment: Add `a.out` to the .gitignore?

Comment: Have you tried just adding a.out to the .gitignore?

Comment: Would that work even if a.out is inside subdir and .gitignore is in the root of repo? git still shows './' to be added when I do `git status` inside program2 dir

Comment: Put in `.gitignore` only the patterns that identify the files you want to ignore. For `C` programming you probably want to ignore `*.o`, `a.out` and the executable files; you better create them in a separate directory and ignore the entire directory. Don't put `*` in `.gitignore` in the source code directory; you'll regret later.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation of `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) or type `git help ignore` on your shell prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to create a `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your git project

Then add the `filename` as the (first) line of the `.gitignore` file

ie: `echo cprograms/program1/a.out >> .gitignore`

If you have already started tracking `programs/program1/a.out` you will need to remove it from git history using this command

`git rm --cached programs/program1/a.out`

now, it looks like based on your file structure you are going to have multiple `a.out` files in multiple directories.

I believe something like this will work too.

```
/* .gitignore file in repo root */

cprograms/*/a.out
```

Comment: git status inside program1 dir shows this
`Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 ./
`
what is `./`. It is a.out ?

Comment: `./` is your current directory

Comment: yeah. so why is git showing that on `git status`. Shouldn't it show the only the filenames ?

Comment: `git status` will return file names if they have been modified since your last commit(red) or if if they are staged(green)  -- however this is deviating from the subject matter of your initial question.